# Xcode 11.4 and Canvas not showing using SwiftUI

Tags: canvas, swiftui, xcode11.4

I am on Xcode 11.4, macOS Catalina and developing in SwiftUI solely.  App has already been shipped and now I need to use the canvas which I got rid of before, switching it off and deleting the Preview Provider.  Now I have enabled the Canvas and added the following code at the end of the file, but the Canvas is still not showing.  If I create a new project ... the canvas is showing.  As soon as I add my code ... the canvas disappears.
Please help ...

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After enabling Canvas and the preview code, try doing a clean build.

it would be very helpful if you provided a screenshot of your canvas not working. Also I'm assuming it is not throwing any errors?